# Google adsense getting data on revenue per page

Tags: html, adsense, ads

Is it possible to get the revenue for each individual page (that ads showed on) per month?

Does Google provide a nice API to get this information programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of using just AdSense. I would recommend adding Google Analytics to your site. They will integrate, and you can have the data you need.